# Where should I install navigation package, in kinetic/share folder or catkin/src

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can anyone tell me about the difference between
git clone http(package repository)
and
apt-get install ros-kinetic-package

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272005/where-should-i-install-navigation-package,-in-kinetic/share-folder-or-catkin/src/) by [Dope_man](https://answers.ros.org/users/32111/dope_man/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first gets you a copy of a set of source files, the second a set of binary artefacts that include everything needed to actually *use* the package.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1